# Squeak during clutch in coming from just behind the firewall

Tags: noise, clutch, hyundai, i20

I have a Hyundai i20 with merely 29000 kilometers on the odometer. Recently, while pressing the clutch, during it's last bit of travel it makes a rubbery squeaky noise which is likely coming from just behind the firewall through which the master cylinder rod is going through. I have tried greasing the moving parts of the pedal hinge and all but the sound seems to be coming from behind the firewall. The sound happens when the clutch is pressed but no sound during releasing. Also the sound goes away when the engine is cold after overnight rest. Comes back in a few kilometers. Is it a sign of failing master cylinder?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does it make noise whether the engine is running or not?

Comment: Sounds like one of those "leave it til it becomes an obvious problem" ones. My mates Volvo clutch made an odd sound for several years before there was a bang and a funny shaped spring fell out of the rear of the pedal. Turned out to be a device that helps the user hold the clutch by providing mechanical assistance when the pedal travel went past a central point. Aside from a different clutch feel there haven't been any further reaching effects

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Both. But when I press the clutch after turning off the engine the sound and the resistance is more for the first time. Then it eases off a bit.

Comment: @CaiusJard That boosted my confidence. But honestly speaking I am weirdly allergic to noises in my car and it is bothering me. I spoke to a mechanic over phone and he says it's the master cylinder. Though there's no loss of grip or sign of slippage I am kinda skeptical to take it for a repair or replacement.

Comment: The reason I asked was to see if it went away when the engine was off, which to me would imply there might be a problem with the throwout bearing. If you use an automotive stethoscope, you could pinpoint the issue. Put the end of it on the master cylinder and have someone else operate it. The noise should be apparent there if that's where it's at.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 It is more prominent when engine is off and kind of eases off with engine running. Likely a problem with the hydraulic system?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Well I don't have an automotive stetho but I am a doctor and I do have a medical stetho if that would work 

Comment: If it is more noisy with it off, I'd suggest the engine noise might just be masking it somewhat when running. I'd point towards the master cylinder being at issue, too.

Comment: Personally, I have the exact same noise from my 30 year old mx5, usually it comes on when I use the clutch too much. So far and after 2 years of having this noise the clutch didn't fail or anything. The noise comes and goes, but what it did improve a bit was the flush of the old fluid and replaced with new one. So, my suggestion would be to try this out and see if that makes any difference...

Comment: @Alimba Could be sludge or dirt in the fluid. Yeah good point. The noise comes and goes right. Today I drove for 30km. Didn't make a noise.